Mongodb Query Questions
I am using built-in sample database (restaurants) in MongoDB.
I am trying to run the query below but getting the error below.
Query
db.restaurants.find(
{"grades.1.grade": "A"},
{borough:1, cuisine:1, grades: {$slice: [0,2]},"grades.score": 1}
)
Failed to retrieve documents
[sample_restaurants.restaurants@atlas-1x6mis-shard-0 [replica set: atlas-1x6mis-shard-0]] Database error!
Stacktrace:
|_/ java.lang.Exception: [sample_restaurants.restaurants@atlas-1x6mis-shard-0 [replica set: atlas-1x6mis-shard-0]] Database error!
|____/ Mongo Server error (MongoQueryException): Query failed with error code 31249 with name 'Location31249' and error message 'Path collision at grades.score remaining portion score' on server ac-wc6qid1-shard-00-02.u51wdlv.mongodb.net:27017
Table with the values below.
{borough:1, cuisine:1, grades: {$slice: [0,2]},"grades.score": 1}

Please read this for how you can format your question and code properly. Format the code using block quotes ```like this```.

In the projection:
grades: {$slice: [0,2]} is requesting that the "grades" field contain the first 3 documents from the original grades array, along with all of the original fields.
"grades.score": 1 is requesting that the "grades" field contain an array of objects, each one contain just the score field from all of the original array elements.
The query executor realizes that it cannot do both of these at the same time, so it fails early with a path conflict.
Try changing the fieldname for the slice, like grades_slice: {$slice: [0,2]}.
If you really need to both slice the array and limit which fields are returned from the sliced elements, try using aggregation instead, so you can have more than one projection.
